# Qual a forma mais adequada de armazenar uma referência em um objeto?

Tags: c++, referência

Suponhamos que eu queira criar uma biblioteca, onde um objeto deve receber outro objeto adicionado pelo usuário e armazenar para uso posterior.
Ex:

```
//header.h
class Caixa{
private:
   Botao botoes[5];
public:
   void addBotao(Botao botao){
      int i;
      while(botoes[i]!=NULL)
         i++;
      botoes[i] = botao;
   }
   Botao getBotao(int i){
      return botoes[i];
   }
}

class Botao{
private:
   char nome[10];
public:
   void Botao(char texto[10]){
      nome = texto;
   }
}

//main.cpp
void main(){
   Caixa caixa1 = Caixa();
   Botao botao1 = Botao("clique");
   caixa1.addBotao(botao1);
}
```

Por questões de economia de memória seria interessante passar esse objeto por referência. Mas, considerando que referências devem ser referenciadas na inicialização, me parece que não seria possível armazenar a referência no objeto, certo ?
Usando ponteiros para fazer a passagem, eu não teria segurança de que a variável ainda estaria ali quando eu fosse usar. Podem me dizer qual a forma mais adequada de resolver esse problema ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você quer aprender do jeito certo ou do jeito gambiarra? Vou pelo certo.

Então modernizei seu código usando C++11/14. Não misture C com C++. E se vai usar C++, use o recursos mais modernos a não ser que tenha uma restrição no projeto que está trabalhando (o que não parece ser o caso).

Algumas coisas podem ser um pouco diferentes dependendo da intenção. Provavelmente eu evitaria o `shared_ptr` e tentaria usar o [`unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) ou [`reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper). E provavelmente eu usaria o [`emplace_back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) no lugar do `push_back`, assim não precisaria criar o objeto separadamente, mas depende do que quer.

É possível armazenar a referência, mas provavelmente seria um erro. Com ponteiros brutos é um problema, mas com ponteiros gerenciados dá para ter "segurança".

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class Botao {
private:
   string nome;
public:
   Botao(string texto) {
      nome = texto;
   }
};

class Caixa {
private:
   vector<shared_ptr<Botao>> botoes;
public:
   void addBotao(shared_ptr<Botao> botao) {
      botoes.push_back(botao);
   }
   shared_ptr<Botao> getBotao(int i) {
      return botoes[i];
   }
};

int main() {
   auto caixa1 = Caixa();
   auto botao1 = make_shared<Botao>("clique");
   caixa1.addBotao(botao1);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/3dikfG). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/udpeizlh-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Vector/Composing.cpp).