# O que é uma shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, ponteiro, c++11, smart-pointer

Se possível, com um exemplo de código, pois isso que falta na referência para realmente entender quando e como usar o `shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você o usa quando deseja criar um ponteiro para algum objeto e deixar o C++ gerenciar isso para você. O objeto será automaticamente destruído quando não houver mais referências para ele.

É preferível usar o [`unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) sempre que possível. O [`shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) usa um contador de referências para controlar se ele ainda precisa estar ativo. Além do custo de memória para armazenar o contador é necessário incrementar esse contador toda vez que cria uma nova referência e decrementar e verificar se chegou a zero quando uma referência para o objeto é abandonada. Isso pode não ser tão barato em alguns cenários. Fica pior se tiver que sincronizar o incremento/decremento em ambiente de concorrência. O `unique_ptr` não tem custo algum (nem memória, nem processamento, zero mesmo), mas só pode ter uma referência para o objeto, o que é o mais comum que ocorre.

Ambos não eliminam o custo gerenciamento da alocação em si no *heap*, apenas garantem que um objeto não seja liberado antes, nem depois do momento que ele realmente não ter mais serventia.

É uma forma de coletor de lixo, ainda que não tradicional como alguns conhecem e por isso tem outros compromissos, vantagens e desvantagens.

[Documentação](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

Tem um [exemplo aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/99591/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Por mais de uma referência a um objeto, você se refere a situação de que quando, por exemplo, se passado como parâmetro o mesmo ter uma cópia que as alterações não são aplicadas na origem? (quando a passagem não é por referência)

Comment: Pelo contrário, o que você está dizendo são referências para objetos distintos. O `shared_ptr` serve para o mesmo objeto. O que uma referência alterar na objeto, as demais verão a alteração.

Comment: Não sei exatamente o porquê, mas me fez lembrar de DCOM e seus famosos *smart pointers* com `CComPtr` (Deus me proteja... em nome do pai, do filho e do espírito santo, amém).

Comment: @LuizVieira Você sabe que é diferente :)

Comment: Sim, claro. Mas me lembrou daquela coisa bizarra da Microsoft (e me deu uns calafrios aqui rs).